# filter.date not working GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, date

I am trying to filter deforestation alerts (image collection) by date.
However, it does not work, because my output is empty.

My code is the following:

```
var date1 = ee.Number(fecha1.getRelative('day','year')); 
var date2 = ee.Number(fecha2.getRelative('day','year'));
var dateYear1 = dateSelect1.slice(0,4);
var dateYear2 = dateSelect2.slice(0,4);

var timeNow = ee.Date(Date.now());
var yearNow = timeNow.get('year');
var yearPre = timeNow.advance(-1,'year').get('Year');
var yearNowS = ee.String(yearNow).getInfo();
var yearPreS = ee.String(yearPre).getInfo();
var yearNowShort = ee.String(yearNow).slice(2,4).getInfo();
var yearPreShort = ee.String(yearPre).slice(2,4).getInfo();

var bandasPre = ['Date' + yearPreShort,'Alert'+ yearPreShort];
var bandasAct = ['Date'+ yearNowShort,'Alert'+ yearNowShort];
var bandasRADD;
var raddfilter;
var mosaicoLandsatEnero;
var raddLast;
var lastAlerts,lastAlerts2,lastAlerts3,lastAlerts4,lastAlerts5;
var raddRegion = raddConfirmedCollection.filterBounds(region); //image collection 

//to check if fecha 1 & fecha2 are correct: 
print(fecha1, fecha2, 'fechas') //correct (Date (2021-01-08 00:00:00), Date (2022-06-14 00:00:00)) 

//Selection of alerts case 1 (yearpre-yearpre)
if(dateYear1 === yearPreS && dateYear2 === yearPreS ){
  raddfilter = raddRegion.filterDate(fecha1,fecha2);//something goes wrong here
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?
The link to the script is here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/dfcad338aab040ebbe0a751c80b1a7f7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the help of a friend we figured out what the problem was :)

The dates that the code tried to read had different properties than expected, so I had to transform them first. I did it by:

```
//Radd alerts 
var radd = ee.ImageCollection('projects/radar-wur/raddalert/v1');

//convert dates to millis 
var date1mili = fecha1.millis();
var date2mili = fecha2.millis();

//convert dates to days in format of Julian 
var date1julian = fecha1.getRelative('day', 'year');
var date2julian = fecha2.getRelative('day', 'year');

//select only years 
var date1year = fecha1.get('year');
var date2year = fecha2.get('year');

//generate dates in format YYDOY 
var date1yydoy = ee.Number.expression('(a-2000)*1000+b', {a:date1year, b:date1julian});
var date2yydoy = ee.Number.expression('(a-2000)*1000+b', {a:date2year, b:date2julian});


//filter alerts to dates when introduced 
var filtroDate1 = ee.Filter.gte('system:time_end', date1mili);
var filtroDate2 = ee.Filter.lte('system:time_end', date2mili);

//filter radd alerts for dates and location
var filteredRaddAlerts = radd.filter(ee.Filter.and(filtroDate1,filtroDate2)).filterBounds(region);
var RADDfirst = filteredRaddAlerts.sort('system:time_end',true).first().clip(region);
var RADDlast = filteredRaddAlerts.sort('system:time_end',false).first().clip(region);


//mask out confirmed alerts 
var raddConfirmadas = RADDlast.where(RADDlast.select('Alert').neq(3),0);

//Filter alerts for specific dates
var raddFecha1 = raddConfirmadas.where(RADDlast.select('Date').lt(date1yydoy),0);
var raddFecha2 = raddFecha1.where(RADDlast.select('Date').gt(date2yydoy),0);
var raddmasked = raddFecha2.selfMask();

print(radd,filteredRaddAlerts,RADDfirst,RADDlast,raddmasked)

Map.addLayer(raddmasked)
```